# Rendering from a child to a parent using refs and portals in React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to render a react portal from a child component into a parent component using a ref created on the parent. I've tried to get this to work but in my experiments `ReactDOM.createPortal()`  fails to render anything.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0qk3pxrkwn

Note that the text "I will render in my parent" is never rendered.

Am I doing something wrong here?

The context of this is that my child component is a dropdown, and my parent component wraps the child in `overflow: hidden` in order to achieve some funky styles. To show the dropdown part of the child, I will need to render that content in the parent. Portals seem like a pretty good pattern for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

From [official portals doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html):

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists **outside** the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

If you'd like to do it anyway, do something like that in the parent component:

```
<ParentComponent>
  <ChildWhichCreatesPortal />
  <PortalContainer />
</ParentComponent>
```

where `PortalContainer` is something which never rerenders:

```
class PortalContainer extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false
  }

  render() {
    <div id="id-to-find-dom-node"></div>
  }
}
```

The way I specified above should work, but I didn't try

Answer (score 1):

I've built a library to fix this exact problem, since although it's possible with portals, it's not easy. Portals are mainly designed to send content *outside* your main tree, not across it, and require you to get quite involved with the raw DOM for yourself to do so.

You can see the full details at https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal.

In your example, a solution would look something like:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as portals from "react-reverse-portal";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Create a portal node: the link between the two ends of the portal
    this.portalNode = portals.createPortalNode();
  }

  render() {
    // Place an OutPortal somewhere: this is where the content will appear
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child portalNode={this.portalNode} />
        <portals.OutPortal node={this.portalNode} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Child = props => {
  // Place an InPortal somewhere: this is where the content is defined
  return <portals.InPortal node={props.portalNode}>
    <p>I will render in my parent</p>,
  </portals.InPortal>
};

function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```